# ng-disabled in Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In My Angular UI I want to disable a submit button if

```
1) All the inputs are null or empty
2) If the endDate field is less than the startDate itself
```

What I did is ...

```
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" style="width:100px;" value="Submit" 
ng-disabled="groupMembershipUserInputForm.$invalid || !(!!groupmembership.chapterCode || !!groupmembership.groupCode || 
!!groupmembership.groupName || !!groupmembership.createdBy || 
!!groupmembership.createdDate || !!groupmembership.startDate ||
!!groupmembership.endDate || !!groupmembership.losCode 
|| groupmembership.compareAgainstStartDate(groupmembership.endDate) )" />
```

All the strings empty/null checks are working fine except the date compare check .

In my controller the method looks like

```
$scope.groupmembership.compareAgainstStartDate = function (item) {
    var startDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.startDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
    var endDate = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.groupmembership.endDate), 'MM/dd/yyyy');

    if (endDate < startDate) {
        $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = true;
    }
    else
        $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = false;

    return $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput;
};
```

It is being hit , but I don't know why the disabling not happening if the date compare fails .

Please help me .

Comment: check this example http://jsfiddle.net/peceLm14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first :

> All the inputs are null or empty

For this just add a `required` to all your `input/select/...`
If you do so `groupMembershipUserInputForm.$invalid` will be true if one of the required fields is not filled.

This will simplify greatly you `ng-disabled` to the following :

```
ng-disabled="groupMembershipUserInputForm.$invalid || 
    groupmembership.compareAgainstStartDate(groupmembership.endDate)"
```

This is a first valid working step. Now if you want to go further you could create a directive and have something like :

```
<input ng-model="afterDate" date-greater-than="beforeDate"/>
```

This will be usefull if you have other forms than need this. If you're interested to do this i suggest you to google something like "angular js custom validation form directive" and if you have trouble with that directive, after trying on your own, come back to us into another question.

FInally if you master custom validation form you could use `angular-message`. it's a little addon specifically designed to display error from forms.

Here is a sample code from https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages :

```
<form name="myForm">
   <input 
    type="text" 
    name="username" 
    ng-model="user.username" 
    ng-minlength="3" 
    ng-maxlength="8"
    required>

    <div ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
        <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
        <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
        <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
        <p ng-message="myCustomErrorField">Your name is <your custom reason></p>
    </div>
   <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic pretty much right, I have doubt on your `$scope.groupmembership.startDate` and `$scope.groupmembership.endDate` because if I provide correct dates, then it is working as expected. Can you please try by providing some constant date to verify whether your function is behaving properly or not. For me it is working fine with actual date values.

```
$scope.startDate = $filter('date')(new Date("07/02/2016"), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
$scope.endDate = $filter('date')(new Date("0710/2016"), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example dates are **string type** so you may not get correct result. To compare date first convert it to **time** using `getTime()` that will give you exact result. No need to use filter for date check.

just use like:

```
$scope.groupmembership.compareAgainstStartDate = function () {
    var startDate = new Date($scope.groupmembership.startDate);
    var endDate = new Date($scope.groupmembership.endDate);

    if (endDate.getTime() < startDate.getTime()) {
        $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = true;
    }
    else
        $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = false;

    return $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert **startdate** and **enddate** to **milliseconds**, and compare them.

Try the below code once:

```
$scope.groupmembership.compareAgainstStartDate = function () {
    var startDate = new Date($scope.groupmembership.startDate).getTime();
    var endDate = new Date($scope.groupmembership.endDate).getTime();

    if (endDate < startDate) {
       $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = true;
    } else {
       $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput = false;
    }

    return $scope.groupmembership.toggleInvalidInput;
};
```